# Visualizing points with different colours based on field from polygon layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, color, point-in-polygon, visualisation

I am aiming to create a map showing species location records as points. I need to make the points different colours based on land type which is a polygon layer. So I want my species points to be a different colour to represent which land type they occur in. For example, records in farmland = blue, records in forest = green, records in grassland = yellow, etc.

I can count points in the layer etc. based on tools available, but I just want to show them differently based on the different land types on the map. I need a straightforward way to do it and I think this should exist. I can complete by selecting by each land type etc. individually, but with the amount of species involved this seems too onerous.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new field using Field Calculator to fetch the region name from the region layer. Then symbolize the point layer using the new field.

Example:

```
array_to_string(overlay_intersects('district_layer', kommunnamn))
```

[image]

Comment: Or even use the expression directly for categorized rendering (in the `Value` field) instead of creating a field. However, for larger datasets, rendering might become slow.

Comment: Nice, didnt think of that

Answer (score 2):

A bit dirty solution using the ["Expression String Builder"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#the-expression-string-builder) and the [`CASE`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=case%20when#case) function for your points

[image: widnow]

The following expression-like can be used:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN array_to_string(overlay_intersects('poly_test', "type")) = 'Type 1' THEN '#0A97B0'
    WHEN array_to_string(overlay_intersects('poly_test', "type")) = 'Type 2' THEN '#1C7947'
    ELSE '#FFD3E1'
END
```

It contains several functions: [`overlay_intersects()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=case%20when#overlay-intersects) and [`array_to_string()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=case%20when#array-to-string).

Your input/output may look like this:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to spatial join them then add a field and calculate it with the landcover type. You could then export it as a new feature class or keep the join.